# PageSpeed suggests jpg can be compressed 31% while grunt/imagemin says "Already Optimized"?

Tags: gruntjs, pagespeed, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I'm following up to an advise by google pagespeed to optimize the static/images on our website. After i integrated grunt/imagemin with the default optimizer (jpegtran for jpg) I found that many image files are indeed optimized with an average of 20%, however the large image file that google pagespeed suggests is found to be already optimized?

`Reading project/apps/frontend/static/images.optimize/<...>.jpg...OK
Writing project/apps/setup/static/images/<...>.jpg...OK
✔ project/apps/frontend/static/images.optimize/<...>.jpg (already optimized)`

Grunt config:

`imagemin: {
            dynamic: {
                options: {
                    optimizationLevel: 3
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= ... %>/static/images.optimize/',
                    src: [
                        '**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'
                    ],
                    dest: '.../images/'
                }]
            }
        },`

Answer (score 0):

First, try changing the optimizationLevel. The highest compression level is 7, lowest is 0, and the default is 3.

If changing it to a higher level does not work, try using an online compressor, like [kraken](https://kraken.io/web-interface) or [tinypng](https://tinypng.com/), which also does jpg.